# How to get CapsLock-Shift-X working when it shows no scancode?

Tags: keyboard, pop-os

I have mapped <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as an additional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but cannot use it for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shortcut (while others like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> work fine),

When running `sudo showkey -s` and pressing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, I see a code for each key. Doing the same for <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shows the codes for <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> but nothing for <kbd>X</kbd>. Is there anything I can do to make this shortcut work?

(I'm using X11 with Pop!_OS on Linux 6.6.10 on a Lenovo X13 laptop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that no scancode is produced, my best guess is that your keyboard doesn't support this particular combination of key presses. Manufacturers skimp on costs by optimizing the keyboard matrix by leaving out unusual key combinations. This phenomenon is called [key rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_rollover).

Try this on your keyboard: while holding both Shift keys simultaneously, type out the entire alphabet. My 2023 Thinkpad T14s misses M, T, X, Y and Z. On my external keyboards (Ducky One and Leopold FC750) this works fine on the same machine.

So, as a solution: switch to a different keyboard or use a different key combination.

Comment: That looks quite right, thanks! (as for the shift-shift-alphabet my Thinkpad misses C, M, T, V, X, Y, Z).